# How to add double qoutes and comma to each item in a big list automatically?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a big list like

```
Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
Andorra
Angola
.
.
```

How do I make the list like following automatically with some linux utility without having to do it manually?

```
"Afghanistan",
"Albania",
"Algeria",
"Andorra",
"Angola",
.
.
```

Comment: Use your editor's search and replace feature.

Comment: @torazaburo How to do that? Search with what and replace with what?

Comment: Search for beginning of line and replace with `"`. Search for end of line and replace with `",`. Or, depending on your editor's capabilities, do a regexp search for something like `^(.*)$` and replace with `"\1",`.

Comment: @torazaburo Worked perfectly in sublime text 3. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, using AWK:

```
awk '{ print "\"" $0 "\","; }' <myFile
```

Comment: Nice, but actually `<` is not needed. It may be written is a shorter form, like `awk '$0="\""$0"\","' inputfile`. As the result is always not null string, it works well for each line.

Comment: You can also remove the `;` -> `awk '{print "\""$0"\","}' myFile`

Answer (score 2):

And with sed

```
bash-3.2$ sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1",/g' myFile
"Afghanistan",
"Albania",
"Algeria",
"Andorra",
"Angola",
```

Or  `sed 's/.*/"&",/g' myFile`

Answer (score 2):

using sed:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1",/g' file
```

using while loop:

```
while read line;do echo \"$line\",;done < file
```

using for loop:

```
for line in `cat file`;do echo \"$line\",;done
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's a pure bash/zsh version:

```
while read line ; do echo "\"$line\"" ; done <myFile
```

Answer (score 2):

simpliest should be sed that is mainly made for that

```
sed 's/.*/"&",/' SourceFile > DestFile
```

- no need of other option/action in posix
- if with GNU sed **and** DestFile is the same as SourceFile

  `sed -i "" -e 's/.*/"&",/' SourceFile`

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` in a better way

```
awk '$0="\""$0"\","' yourfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly say:

```
sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/",/' file
```

With this, you are saying:

- replace the beginning of the line (`^`) with `"`.
- replace the end of the line (`$`) with `",`.

Answer (score 1):

Use your editor's search and replace feature.

Search for beginning of line and replace with `"`. Search for end of line and replace with `",`. Or, depending on your editor's capabilities, do a regexp search for something like `^(.*)$` and replace with `"\1",`.